# add a button to "jquery file upload"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I added a button to my "blueimp-jquery-file-upload" page. It pops up when the upload is complete, next to the "delete" button.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger processData" data-type="{%=file.processDataType%}" data-url="{%=file.processUrl%}">
    <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
    <span>Process the uploaded file</span>
</button>
```

I created it simply by copying the code for the delete button and changing the names (i.e. deleteType -> processDataType, deleteUrl -> processDataUrl, ...)

How and where can I write a function that is called when the button is clicked? The idea is being able to trigger the processing of each uploaded file individually. I'm using a php framework.

Thanks,
AC

Answer (score 0):

To run a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#buttonid').click(function(){
      "Your function"
    });
  });
</script>
```

You can use a different selector, but adding an id is the simplest way to get around with it.